# Cakephp 3.0 login as Anonymous

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I write system using Cakephp 3.0 and I need to have login as registrated user and login ad anonymous user. I have login as registrated user using login and password. But how to login as anonymous ?
I should add unique name like : user2512 for anonymous user and stre it in cookie or cache?

Comment: Are you wanting to offer a "Guest" login on your site? Presumably this user should have limited permissions?

Comment: yes. Guest couldn't change name, password etc.

Comment: So create a guest user belonging to the guest user group  with the appropriate permissions, assuming you are using group permissions, and then create a form with hidden fields with the guest username and password. This will log the user in as a guest. Or do you want to have multiple guest users?

Comment: I have to multiple guest users like user20123, user12321 and this will temporary users.

Comment: Is there any difference between non logged in users and guest users? If not I would recommend to use auth component's allow, deny and isauthorized methods

Comment: yes. If you not logged you can't do nothing. When you logged as guest you have unique login. non logged see only login form